# Customize header section for UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I'll need to customize the header section of a `UITableViewController` where for each sections a different header text is returned (getting data from datasource as well). This is accomplished using the following:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *temp = [listOfMBeans allKeys];
    DLog(@"MBean details: %@", temp);
    NSString *title = [temp objectAtIndex:section];
    DLog(@"Header Title: %@", title);
    return title;
};
```

This works well and I can see the expected output. However I need to change also the font size of text and after looking at similar questions I've implemented the following:

```
- (UIView *) tableview:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    DLog(@"Custom Header Section Title being set");
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)] autorelease];  

    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)] autorelease];
    label.text = [tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

    [headerView addSubview:label];
    return headerView;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 44.0;
}
```

However it seems that the code is never called. My understanding was that `UITableViewController` is setting by default itself as delegate but it seems I'm wrong.

The `UITableViewController` is created in this way (as part of hierarchical data):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ProjectDetails *detailViewController = [[ProjectDetails alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    detailViewController.project = [listOfMetrics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Push the detail view controller.
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release]; 
}
```

What changes, I should make to make this working? 
Thanks.

Comment: it's not really clear to me, that what are you asking for?

Comment: make sure you set new table view delegate, perhaps in the init method of 'projectDetails' .

Comment: @rptwsthi Basically how to make my UITableViewController ProjectDetails to call viewForHeaderInSection in order to customize header view

Comment: Check the case on the method name... it's tableView, not tableview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set explicitly the delegate:

```
 detailViewController.tableView.delegate = detailViewController;
```

Or you can do it in the controller initial function.

EDIT: your `init` method should conform to the canonical init. Furthermore, it seems to me that you have not created your UITableView. Try and use this code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style { 
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style])) {
        self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
        self.tableView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        self.tableView.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Of course, you could also do all of this in a nib file...

Comment: Ok Definetively I got lost at this point :( I've tried both solution but no luck. Into ProjectDetails.m I've added this `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    UITableViewController *tvc = [super initWithStyle:style];
    tvc.tableView.delegate = self;
    return tvc;
}` but still cannot see `- (UIView *) tableview:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Comment: Ahh that's the trick... I'll need to create my own UITableView and not using the one generated by defaults. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hope I've corrected the code typo's above. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 11):

This question is an older one but I wanted to share my code. I'm using a usual table cell view for my section headers. I have designed it with interface builder and implemented the following delegate method.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"Header"];
  cell.textLabel.text = @"test";
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: why are you using cell for header view? Are you using two types of cells (header/body) for some kind of nested list? I wonder how sns apps implement nested list view and if you are doing similar sort of thing?

Comment: @Eugene because you can design cells in IB. Yes I have nested lists and at least two cell prototypes 'header' and 'item'. I'm not sure how others implement this approach.

Comment: One interesting side effect of doing it this way that I just ran into - you appear to get colored borders around the cell (even when the table has separator set to none). Manually creating and retuning a UIView doesn't have this issue. Note: I only noticed this because I had dark headers.

Comment: @cocoafan ...Nothing is getting display in viewForHeaderInSection.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey Did you also set the identifier to "Header"?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you get the barebones section view up using the UITableViewDelegate methods:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
    UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40.0)];
    header.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:header.frame];
    textLabel.text = @"Your Section Title";
    textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [header addSubview:textLabel];

    return header;
 }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
    return 40.0;
  }
```

Comment: Since you've set the label frame equals to the hearder frame, the header backgroundColor instruction is useless since it's replaced by the textLabel backgroundColor one

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:  In your ProjectDetails.h declare a `UIView *tableHeader` and also an accessor method `- (UIView *)tableHeader;`.  Then in the implementation file:

```
- (UIView *)tableHeader {
    if (tableHeader)
        return tableHeader;

    tableHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
    // addlabel
    return tableHeader;
}
```

In viewDidLoad, call: `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [self tableHeader];`

I don't believe you'll need to use the heightForHeaderInSection method.

Comment: Hi Mark, I've tried this but although I can see that the method is called section header is not changed :( I still see my section text that is coming out from the deafult `(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Comment: If you're trying to create custom headers for multiple sections in the tableView, then I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes, for each section I've an header with different text (coming out from datasource as well). I'll edit the original question to make this point clear.